# execvp doesn't work with other code

Tags: execvp

I am trying to make a program where the user is continuously prompted for a command (ls -l for example) I'm tokenizing input into commands and storing them in an array of char*. When I call execvp to execute the command:

char* paramList[2] = {"/bin/ls", "-l"};

execvp(paramList[0], paramList);

nothing happens. I have another program with nothing in it except for the execvp call and the ls -l command hard coded and that works. However ass soon as a add in anything, even an unused variable the code stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Your array (paramList) is one entry short.

The array given as the second argument of execvp must end with a NULL entry, thus 3 values in the array, versus the two you currently have.

```
char* paramList[3] = { "/bin/ls", "-l", NULL };
execvp(paramList[0], paramlist);
```

Should work as expected.

Probably better/easier to use:

```
char* paramList[] = { "/bin/ls", "-l", NULL };
```

and let the compiler count them.